# python: how to perform whois with uwhoisd proxy

Tags: python, proxy, network-programming, client, whois

I'm trying to use the undocumented library [uwhoisd](https://github.com/kgaughan/uwhoisd) and I cannot figure out how to successfully call the `whois()` function on the `UWhois` object.

I start the deamon by calling a file *UwhoisDeamon.py* with following content:

```
import uwhoisd
uwhoisd.main()
```

The argument I give to python is the [*.ini file](https://github.com/kgaughan/uwhoisd/blob/master/extra/uwhoisd.ini) that was included in the *extra* directory when I downloaded the source code

Starting the deamon is successful with following output:

> 2016-04-21 19:00:19,830   INFO:uwhoisd    Reading config file at
>   '/path/to/my/ini/uwhoisd.ini' 2016-04-21
>   19:00:19,838  INFO:uwhoisd    Listen on 0.0.0.0:4243 2016-04-21
>   19:00:19,842  INFO:uwhoisd    Caching activated [2016/04/21 17:00:19]
>   {diesel} WARNING|Starting diesel

Now I'm trying perform a whois on google.com by starting a separate python instance and I get slapped in the face (I reused [this](https://github.com/kgaughan/uwhoisd/blob/master/tests/utils.py) code):

```
from os import path
import uwhoisd
from uwhoisd.utils import make_config_parser

HERE = path.dirname(__file__)

def create_uwhois():
    """Prepare a UWhois object for testing."""
    config = path.join(HERE, 'uwhoisd.ini')
    parser = make_config_parser(uwhoisd.CONFIG, config)
    uwhois = uwhoisd.UWhois()
    uwhois.read_config(parser)
    return uwhois

uwhois = create_uwhois()
# uwhois = uwhoisd.UWhois()
result = uwhois.whois("google.com")
print result
```

And here the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.0.201411111611/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 2183, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/home/user/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.0.201411111611/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1622, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/path/to/my/project/Whois/WhoisChecker.py", line 17, in <module>
    result = uwhois.whois("google.com")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uwhoisd/__init__.py", line 137, in whois
    with net.WhoisClient(server, port) as client:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/diesel/client.py", line 16, in __init__
    ip = self._resolve(self.addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/diesel/client.py", line 21, in _resolve
    return resolve_dns_name(addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/diesel/resolver.py", line 67, in resolve_dns_name
    except (NotFound, Timeout):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/diesel/util/lock.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.release()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/diesel/util/lock.py", line 18, in release
    fire(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/diesel/core.py", line 92, in fire
    return current_loop.fire(*args, **kw)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fire'
```

It seems to me that the [diesel](http://diesel.io/tutorial) library which is used by uwhoisd to communicate between client and deamon application requires some special conditions to make it work. From what I can see the mysterious `current_loop` is not running. However I never used diesel before and I have no idea what to do. It seems to me that I have to somehow start that diesel loop before I can perform those whois queries.

A working example would be great. The main reason why I'm choosing uwhoisd is that I can perform whois on exotic websites such as "win.win". It also caches responses which means more speed and less network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of uwhoisd here.

First up, get rid of `UwhoisDeamon.py`: it's a daemon, not a library. You're meant to run the daemon and then query it with a whois client. You don't have to write any additional code to get it up and running. It already installs a working console script that does the right thing.

When you install it, say, into a virtual environment, it will create a script called `uwhoisd` that you use to run the daemon. Here's an example:

```
$ virtualenv env
$ env/bin/pip install uwhoisd
Downloading/unpacking uwhoisd
  Downloading uwhoisd-0.0.7-py2-none-any.whl
... installation log ...
Successfully installed uwhoisd diesel greenlet twiggy pyopenssl flask http-parser dnspython six cryptography Werkzeug Jinja2 itsdangerous idna pyasn1 setuptools enum34 ipaddress cffi MarkupSafe pycparser
Cleaning up...
```

If you run the daemon without, here's what you should get, assuming you had all the necessary system packages installed:

```
$ env/bin/uwhoisd
Usage: uwhoisd <config>
```

uwhoisd requires a configuration file that tells it how to talk to the various WHOIS servers it needs to be able to query. You can download the file like so:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kgaughan/uwhoisd/master/extra/uwhoisd.ini
```

Running the daemon with this config file should give you the following:

```
$ env/bin/uwhoisd uwhoisd.ini 
2016-05-03 17:41:25,028 INFO:uwhoisd    Reading config file at 'uwhoisd.ini'
2016-05-03 17:41:25,038 INFO:uwhoisd    Listen on 0.0.0.0:4243
2016-05-03 17:41:25,058 INFO:uwhoisd    Caching activated
```

The second line indicates what address and port the daemon is running on. In this case, it's running on all interfaces on port 4243, so you can now issue requests to it on that port (in a different terminal window):

```
$ whois -h localhost -p 4243 stackoverflow.com
Domain Name: STACKOVERFLOW.COM 
Registry Domain ID: 108907621_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN 
...
```

And you should see the following additional log lines in the terminal the daemon is running in:

```
2016-05-03 17:43:36,841 INFO:uwhoisd    Querying whois.verisign-grs.com about stackoverflow.com
2016-05-03 17:43:37,283 INFO:uwhoisd    Recursive query to whois.name.com about stackoverflow.com
```

You shouldn't be using uwhois's internals directly: it's a daemon and isn't designed to be used as a library, certainly not outside of diesel's event loop like that, which is why you got that traceback. Run the daemon with the config file, however, and you'll be golden.

Unfortunately, I haven't had time to write all the documentation for the daemon it needs, but I'm hoping to resolve this soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess that means that I'll have to parse the output myself, but that's not a big problem.

Comment: Unavoidable, I'm afraid, though for gTLDs, there's a fixed format these days that's easy to parse: https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en#whois

For thin registries (.com, .net, .jobs, &c.), not all registrars use that format, unfortunately. For ccTLDs (two-letter domain names), it's a total crapshoot. :-/